# Compare byte32 Keccak256 to the same Keccak256 stored in a byte32 array

Tags: solidity, truffle, hash, bytes, keccak

I want my function to be able to accept an array of Hashed secrets as a parameter and since solidity doesn't allow for strings, I had to use a byte32[].

The string parameter is an intake for the user's secret which I am hashing with Keccak256 which should convert it to a byte32 value.

Since (or so I think) the hashed secret string is a byte32 and so is the hashed secret stored in the first element of the byte32 array, the assertion should evaluate to true when comparing them

Test:

```
it("Checking secrets", function() {
    return myContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
      contract = instance;
      return contract.test.call("hello", ["1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"])
      .then(function(testVals){
        assert.equal(testVals[0].valueOf(), testVals[1][0].valueOf())
      })
  });
});
```

Function:

```
function test(string val1, bytes32[] val2) public returns(bytes32, bytes32[]){
        return(keccak256(val1), val2);
    }
```

Result:

```
AssertionError: expected '0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8' to equal '0x3163386166663935303638356332656434626333313734663334373232383762'
```

Comment: Try a leading `0x`, i.e. `0x1c8aff95...`

Comment: wow such a silly mistake lol... thank you so much for checking back in with me since the AM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@smarx was correct. I had to add a leading "0x" to the hashes I was passing to the byte32 array:

```
it("Checking secrets", function() {
    return myContract.deployed().then(function(instance){
      contract = instance;
      return contract.test.call("hello", ["0x1c8aff950685c2ed4bc3174f3472287b56d9517b9c948127319a09a7a36deac8"])
      .then(function(testVals){
        assert.equal(testVals[0].valueOf(), testVals[1][0].valueOf())
      })
  });
});
```